# Printing a csv 'none' error

Tags: python, search, csv

trying to print a csv, and i keep getting the error 'none' I want to simply list the contents of the csv. I have two days, saturday and sunday

Comment: Your functions don't `return` anything, so it prints _None_.

Comment: Please fix indentation, otherwise it might be hard to tell  what the problem might really be.

Answer (score 0):

your friday function is not returning anything.

If you are trying to print out the data in the file you have to iterate through it

`csvFile = csv.reader(open('friday.csv','rb'))`

> Each row read from the csv file is returned as a list of strings.

```
for line_list in csvFile:
  # do something with the dat
```

Answer (score 0):

The methods `friday` and `saturday` do not contain any `return` statements. By default, Python returns `None` when it reaches the end of a function without encountering a `return` statement.

Add a `return` (and code to actually read the file), like this:

```
def friday():
   with csv.reader(open('friday.csv','rb')) as csvFile:
       return '\n'.join(' - '.join(csvFile))
```